# Make words-art in Inkscape — How can I cut the words out of a shape?

Tags: inkscape, mask, word-cloud

I want to create a word-cloud or you call a tag-cloud, but I have a problem cutting the words out of the shape that I want. Anyway, here's the demo word-cloud:

[image]

I want the yellow "DEMO" text to overlap the heart shape, and disappear when it goes out of the shape. Also, I want to keep the color of both the heart and the text. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If you don't really get what i mean, i mean to make the words be "Erased" at the edge of the heart shape. To make the words only appear inside the heart, and cut at the edge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Convert text to path using Path-object to path
2. Ungroup text objects
3. Use path-combine on selected objects.
4. Duplicate the underlying object (the heart shape in your case)
5. Use path-division and delete the text which is outside the underlying shape as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Group texts.
2. Duplicate shape and change its **color** to text **color**.
3. Select *first* the created group and then the duplicated shape.
4. ***Object/Clip/Apply***.

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip-Clipping.html